# Extract private key and write to a new file in perl

Tags: perl

Simply put, I want to extract the entire private key, listed below, from trust.pem and save that text to a new file (tmp6.pem), using Perl. My current implementation only gives me the first for letters of the key.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is my code, thus far:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use FileHandle;

use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock :seek); # import LOCK_* constants

my $F_IN = FileHandle->new("<trust.pem");
my $F_OUT = FileHandle->new(">tmp6.pem");

while (my $line = $F_IN->getline) {
    if ($line =~ m|(MIID)|) {
        $F_OUT->print("$1\n");
    }
}

$F_IN->close();
$F_OUT->close();
```

Comment: Nitpick: What you're working with there is an SSL certificate (in PEM format), not a key.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This feels a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if you're copying text from one `pem` file to another, then you probably actually still want to keep the delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will skip the first and last lines of the input file by using the [input line number](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) to detect the first line and checking whether the next read would return [end of file](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) to detect the last line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, '<', 'trust.pem') or die $!;
open(my $out, '>', 'tmp6.pem') or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    last if eof($in);
    print $out $_;
}

close($in);
close($out);
```

If you don't mind reading the entire file into memory---which is no problem at all in this case---you could use [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) and [pop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) to remove the first and last lines from the array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, '<', 'trust.pem') or die $!;
my @lines = <$in>;
close($in);

shift(@lines);
pop(@lines);

open(my $out, '>', 'tmp6.pem') or die $!;
print $out @lines;
close($out);
```

Note that the previous examples won't work very well if you have any leading or trailing blank lines. In that case, I'd probably do something like this instead, which skips PEM file headers/footers and lines containing only whitespace:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, '<', 'trust.pem') or die $!;
open(my $out, '>', 'tmp6.pem') or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
    next unless /\S/;
    next if /^-----/;
    print $out $_;
}

close($in);
close($out);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.